# Scala enum - Java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am getting

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Range.Value is not supported.

Appreciate any pointers on this

```
object Range extends Enumeration {
  type Range = Value

  val RangeMedium = Value("Range Medium")
  val RangeHigh = Value("Range Higher")
  val RangeNotEnough = Value("Range Not enough")
  val NotApplicable = Value("Not Applicable")

}



val getRange = udf((p1: Double, p2: Double) => {
    if (p1 >= 5 && p1 < 10 && p2 >= 1) {
      Some(Range.RangeMedium)
    }
    else if (p1 >= 10 && p2 >= 1) {
      Some(Range.RangeHigh)
    }
    else {
      Some(Range.NotApplicable)
    }
  })

ds = Seq(9,10).toDF("p1","p2")

ds.withColumn("level",getRange($"p1",$"p2")).show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're returning a string from the UDF, you can try casting the enum value to a string using `.toString`:

```
object Range extends Enumeration {
  type Range = Value

  val RangeMedium = Value("Range Medium")
  val RangeHigh = Value("Range Higher")
  val RangeNotEnough = Value("Range Not enough")
  val NotApplicable = Value("Not Applicable")
}

val getRange = udf((p1: Double, p2: Double) => {
    if (p1 >= 5 && p1 < 10 && p2 >= 1) {
      Range.RangeMedium.toString
    }
    else if (p1 >= 10 && p2 >= 1) {
      Range.RangeHigh.toString
    }
    else {
      Range.NotApplicable.toString
    }
})

val ds = Seq((9,10)).toDF("p1","p2")

ds.withColumn("level",getRange($"p1",$"p2")).show()
+---+---+------------+
| p1| p2|       level|
+---+---+------------+
|  9| 10|Range Medium|
+---+---+------------+
```

Having said that, this kind of operation is also possible using `when` statements instead of a UDF, which should be more performant.

Comment: Thank you.. curious why did you removed the Some? also is there any option to get the string value from Enum without type casting again as the underlying type is already string

Comment: I don't think the underlying type is a string. If you do `Range.RangeHigh.getClass` you'll see that it's of `scala.Enumeration$Val` type

Comment: I also don't understand why you want to use Some...

Comment: Thanks it worked.  Some of my udfs are unable to determine the return type so i have this habit of adding some to return values from the UDFs.  realized its not required.